# How to check complete source code in IE and Mozilla

Tags: html, internet-explorer, debugging, firefox

I am stuck at really strange issue.I am working on a application which uses sitemesh.
The current page on which I am working have following structure

```
Decorator (main.html)
 -Inner HTML page with 3 tabs (menu.html)
     - Tab 1  (add.html page for Tab1)
     - Tab 2  (edit.html page for Tab2)
     - Tab 3  (dispaly.html page for Tab3)
```

For each tab `href` is defined which links to corresponding page i.e. add.html,edit.html or dispaly.html, Which are dispalyed under tab.Like

```
<a href="/myApp/request/form/AddForm/1761?menuId=app.approve.new" title="Add Request">
```

So I deal with 3 html pages on a single screen.

In IE or Mozilla when I selct any tab and go to `view source` option it just dispaly source code for decorator i.e. main.html,inner page i.e. menu.html but I cann't see the source code for selected tabs html file i.e. for add.html/edit.html/dispaly.html.
Its really strange for me. I need to check complete source code.
Is there any way to check complete source code ?

Comment: `view source` only shows the content of the original HTML page. If you add elements via JavaScript, e.g. via Ajax, you have to inspect the generated DOM.

Comment: @Felix: How can I inspect generated DOM in IE ?

Comment: @Felix: Thanks :) You were 17 sec fast than Jamie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Firefox there's the option to "View Generated Source" from the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/).

This will bring up all source code currently being used in the page, whether natural or generated by some form of client-side script, etc.

**UPDATE**

For IE, you may find that the [Internet Explorer Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) Toolbar has similar functionality.

Comment: What about IE ? I need to test application on IE 6 to 9.

Comment: Thanks. now it don't seems strange anymore.